# Does Hibernate obtains implicit locking for update query

Tags: hibernate, locking

I am using hibernate with spring boot, mariadb.
I am executing an update named query, inside a transactional repository method.
The query looks something like

```
update personDetails set status='married' where personeName='abc' and personStatus='unmarried'
```

After this i go to update other table.

This flow can be executed by 2 separate threads. What I want is to allow only one thread to proceed further, and stop the other thread. So the thread which is able to update the person status, should proceed further and the other thread should be stopped. So I want to achieve some kind of locking on this update query. So the question is, do I need to exclusively take any lock on the row before updating, or hibernate/db will take care of this.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the MariaDB [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/set-transaction/):

> For UPDATE and DELETE statements, locking depends on whether the statement uses a unique index with a unique search condition (such as WHERE id = 100), or a range-type search condition (such as WHERE id > 100). For a unique index with a unique search condition, **InnoDB locks only the index record found**, not the gap before it.  For range-type searches, InnoDB locks the index range scanned, using gap locks or next-key (gap plus index-record) locks to block insertions by other sessions into the gaps covered by the range.

So, the default behavior for MariaDB (and MySQL) during an update is that at the very least, the particular record would be locked from another process trying to update it.  On InnoDB, if a suitable index be not available, then possibly more than just the record would be locked.  On other engines, e.g. MyISAM, the documentation also says that the entire table could be locked.

So, unless Hibernate is doing some non standard plumbing under the hood, your concern should not be an issue.  Note that I did not discuss what would happen if another process were to try to *read* the row which is being updated.  Every database handles this differently.  But, you did not mention that this is a concern.